# C# Static arrays - assigning values of static array to other static array

Tags: c#, arrays, static

I need to assign values of static array to another static array. But when I do this, if I change first array it effects the other one too. How should I assign these values then?

I simplified my problem with this example:

```
class Program
{
    static double[] a1;
    static double[] a2;

    static double b1;
    static double b2;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //First example
        a1 = new double[5] { 1,2,3,4,5 };
        a2 = new double[5] { 6,7,8,9,10};

        a2 = a1;
        a1[2] = 99;  //I change only a1
        
        Console.WriteLine(a1[2]);        
        Console.WriteLine(a2[2]);
        //Result is:
        // 99
        // 99   why is a2 changed too?       


        //Second example 
        b1 = new double(); 
        b2 = new double(); 
        b1 = 10;
        b2 = 20;

        b2 = b1;
        b1 = 33;

        Console.WriteLine(b1);
        Console.WriteLine(b2);
        //Result is:
        // 33     
        // 10   this is okay
    }
}
```

So when I asign a2 = a1, a2 gets a1's address or something?  But why this does not happen with normal variables like in my second example?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx

Comment: [References Types vs Value Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) I really suggest you to understand this concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign a2=a1 you do a shallow copy. A reference (somehow equivalent to the old pointer) to a1 is copied to a2. They now point to same data and changing one changes the other. To create a deep copy, use the Clone() function, like this:

```
a2 = a1.Clone() as double[];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because a static variable is stored on the heap. Once you assign a1 to a2, you're effectively pointing to the same memory location, which is why the change in one will be present for both a1 and a2.

In the second case, those variables are loaded onto the stack and are value type variables. Hence, only the values are copied.

Answer (score 0):

By assigning a2 = a1 you are not copying the array a1 into a2. a1 and a2 represent references to objects, so when you use a2 = a1 you are only copying reference (and so a2 and a1 refer to the same object which is array { 1,2,3,4,5 }. That is why you are seeing changes made in a1 in a2 (since they are essentially the same).

What you want is copy element by element, something like this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.array.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx